# Closing a fireplace to the inside but opening it to the outside

Tags: fireplace, chimney

We are buying a house that has a fireplace in the den. I want to turn the den into the kitchen.  It’s the perfect space for it in the house. The laundry room is on the other side of the wall, so we have water and there is a gas fireplace on the other wall which we would use for a gas range.
My question is how much would it cost and is it possible to seal off the inside opening of the fireplace and then cut an opening on the outdoor side of the chimney and create an outdoor wood burning fireplace? Do that instead of removing the entire chimney and fireplace. So completely cutting it off from the inside and making it a functional outdoor fireplace instead.

Comment: For an answer to that you'll have to ask a bricklayer
and they'll need to see it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. @Jasen is right: we can't answer that here without a lot more info. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I do not think  you will be able to reverse the opening for several reasons ,cost will be the biggest one ,  the back brick work is the strength for the structure. yes there are see through fireplaces but they were built that way. The hearth area would need to be completely rebuilt it could be done but I believe the cost will be excessive it would probably be less expensive to demo the brickwork repair the walls and ceiling and install a wood stove. I have never seen that large of a repair usually if more than repointing is needed we would install a liner and put a wood stove insert in.

Comment: In the long run, I think you'd find that an outdoor fireplace attached to the building is both a fire hazard and aesthetically unpleasant.  Far better to build a fire pit or similar item away from the house.